# Time Consuming Tensorflow C++ Session->Run - Images for Real-time Inference

Tags: c++, image, tensorflow, real-time, inference

[Tensorflow (TF) on CPU]
I am using the skeleton code provided for C++ TF inference from GitHub [label_image/main.cc] in order to run a frozen model I have created in Python. This model is an FC NN with two hidden layers.

In my current project's C++ code, I run the NN's frozen classifier for each single image (8x8 pixels). For each sample, a Session->Run call takes about 0.02 seconds, which is expensive in my application, since I can have 64000 samples that I have to run.

When I send a batch of 1560 samples, the Session->Run call takes about 0.03 seconds.

Are these time measurements normal for the Session->Run Call? From the C++ end, should I send my frozen model batches of images and not single samples? From the Python end, are there optimisation tricks to alleviate that bottleneck? Is there a way to concurrently do Session-Run calls in C++?

Environment info

Operating System: Linux
Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN: N/A

What other attempted solutions have you tried?

1. I installed TF using the optimised instruction set for the CPU, but it does not seem to give me the huge time saving mentioned in StackOverflow
2. Unified the session for the Graph I created.

**EDIT**
*It seems that MatMul is the bottleneck -- Any suggestions how to improve that?*

*Should I use 'optimize_for_inference.py' script for my frozen graph?*

*How can you measure the time in Python with high precision?*

[Timeline for feeding an 8x8 sample and getting the result in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E9jU.png)

[Timeline for feeding an 8x8 batch and getting the result in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEAKx.png)

Comment: It's quite normal that batching will give much higher throughput for the matrix multiplications in a fully connected layer. However, 0.02 seconds seems like a long time for running a 2-layer NN on an 8x8 image, and the constant overhead of a `Session::Run()` should only be around 20 microseconds. I'd suggest following the [instructions here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3850/measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations#t=201703091728067299583) to collect a timeline that will show how time is being spent, and will point to opportunities for optimization.

Comment: 1. Good that you confirmed that batching will increase the time savings.
2. Is the constant overhead for the Session:Run call for all samples or each sample? For all samples -- correct?
3. Will do the timeline and will post here.

Thanks!

Comment: @mrry Here is the timeline... It seems to me that the MatMul is the bottleneck.. any ideas?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E9jU.png

Comment: It certainly does look that way! How does the timeline compare for the batch case?

Comment: @mrry Here is the one for the batch https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEAKx.png

Should I change the machine I am using? Regarding my recorded time numbers, I am suspecting the precision of my time calculations I wrote?

Comment: Without batching: last operation starts at 0.5ms and takes 0.02ms
With batching: last operation starts at 2ms and takes 0.06 ms

Does that mean the total without batching is 0.07ms and with batching is 2.06ms? Or there are other operations not shown in the timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I have done two things that significantly increased the speed of my application:

1. Compiled TF to work on the optimised ISA of my machine.
2. Applied batching to my data samples.

Please feel free to comment here if you have questions about my answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a similar pipeline, so I wonder how do you transfer the image batch to the tensor in c++?

Comment: You should look up this link https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f